# Ubuntu freezes at boot / many trouble installing Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, nvidia

I have many trouble installing Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 (the same holds for Ubuntu 12.04) on my new desktop PC which I will describe in the following.

**Hardware**

- Processor: Intel Core i5-4570
- Mainboard: Gigabyte GA-H87-HD3
- RAM: 8GB G.Skill 1333MHz CL9
- Graphics Card: Gigabyte GeForce GTX 660 OC
- HDD: Seagate Barracuda 7200.14 1000GB

**Problems / what I have done so far**

1. I installed Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 next to my Windows 7 partition via Ubuntu live USB

   - Problem: Grub did not load. Instead Windows 7 boots.
2. I used Boot-Repair to install Grub correctly. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5989500/) is the output.

   - Problem: Grub loads and I can select Ubuntu for booting, but then my monitor turns off and nothing happens.
3. I replaced the Grub boot parameters "quiet splash" by "text nomodeset"

   - Problem: Ubuntu boots, but X does not start. Instead, I get access to the shell.
4. I executed "apt-get dist-upgrade", installed "nvidia-current" and the Ubuntu mainline kernels "v3.5-quantal" and "v3.10-saucy" for testing.

   - Problem: nothing changed.
5. I tried running "startx" and "service gdm start".

   - Problem: Ubuntu freezes completely.

I have no idea what to do now, because Ubuntu does not show any error at booting. It just does not finish booting.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: we need some logs I guess. I'd start from /var/log/Xorg.0.log

Comment: @Cubiq: Thank you for your fast response! I am currently at work, so I will provide logs when I come home in a few hours.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 13.04 boot into black screen, even after installing nvidia drivers, fail at: "Starting Reload cups, upon starting avahi-daemon..."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/311399/ubuntu-13-04-boot-into-black-screen-even-after-installing-nvidia-drivers-fail)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After writing this question, I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/311399/ubuntu-13-04-boot-into-black-screen-even-after-installing-nvidia-drivers-fail?rq=1) related thread from which mine seems to be a duplicate of. Sorry for this! Fortunately the solution which has been presented there (turning off the Intel graphics card) also works for me, so finally I can boot Ubuntu.

Thank you for your interest!